# SOAP-body auto generated namespace

Tags: soap, xsd, soapui, xml-namespaces

I have to do some support on a single-function SOAP webservice, and I am failing to understand a specific aspect of the WSDL file & the resulting SOAP request as generated by SoapUI.

The WSDL for this service specifies a targetNamespace in the definitions part (`targetNamespace="tetra-river-common-types/trafficinfo`").
If I load the WSDL file into SoapUI, it reads everything perfectly fine; no issues at all with any of the definitions. The types for this service are defined in a single external schema file with the following definition in the WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import namespace="tetra-river-common-types" schemaLocation="tetra-river-interface.xsd" />
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

However, after loading the WSDL file into SoapUI, and opening the auto generated request, it shows the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tet="tetra-river-common-types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tet:TrafficInformation>
         <tet:Item1>?</tet:Item1>
         <!-- several other items with the tet: namespace prefixed -->
      </tet:TrafficInformation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My question is: how is the `tet:` namespace determined by SoapUI? I see no mention of it in either the WSDL file or the XSD file. I assume it takes the first 3 characters from the targetNamespace, but I am unsure.
The problem I am facing is that the webservice itself expects this exact message, but with `tetra:` as the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the wsdl, there is an import of namespace as below:

```
namespace="tetra-river-common-types"
```

And if you see the request in the soapUI, in the very first line has the same *namespace* with prefix `tet` i.e.,

```
xmlns:tet="tetra-river-common-types"
```

Hence, the respective request elements are prefixed with `tet`.

It does not really matter what the prefix is as along the referring to the same namespace.

For more information on namespaces, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)